# Define area routing in Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I define the area routing in the controller as follows:

```
[Area("Product")]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexJson()
    {
        return View("IndexJson");
    }
}
```

And I map the routes in Program.cs as follow:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}"
    );

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

Trying to reach the IndexJson view:

> https://localhost:7207/Product/Products/IndexJson => 404 not found
> https://localhost:7207/Products/IndexJson => Works Fine

I want to achieve /Product/Products/IndexJson to be reachable, what do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up 2 forms of routing. Endpoint routing and attribute routing. The `RouteAttribute` decorating your controller is overriding your endpoint configuration for that specific controller.
The solution is as simple as removing `[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`